# Can strust2 be deployed to Weblogic application server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, configuration, weblogic

I am new to `J2EE` frameworks.

I want to know if Struts2 can be deployed to an Oracle Weblogic application server.

If so, how can I do it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

**J2EE** is up to Java 1.4. 
From Java 1.5 it's called **Java EE**.

Yes, Struts2 web applications, as every other technologies' EAR / WAR, can be deployed on Oracle WebLogic (formerly Bea WebLogic) servers.

The deployment can be done by selecting and uploading the ear through the Web Console (`deployments` section), or through IDE plugins, or with Ant tasks, Maven tasks, etcetera. The exact way depends on the environment you're working on, but the Web Console approach is what you probably want at first, when you simply need to test the hello word and you haven't automatized anything yet.

[image]